# jQuery onClick capture the id of the element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i have many input fields like this

```
<input type="radio" name="name" id="name" onchange="enableTxt()" />
```

when i click this radio button i wanna capture the id of the radio input. i am using the following code

```
function enableTxt() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);
}
```

Am getting this error

```
a.attributes is undefined
```

Comment: Harsha , you need to pass this to the function as argument , that is the issue

Comment: @harsa one suggestion as you are already using jquery, change the inline fucntion to document.ready onchange event , so that it will be clear separation and less changes of making errors like passing values etc

Comment: thanks gov. i think your right

Answer (score 70, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="name" id="name" onchange="enableTxt(this)" />
```

JS:

```
function enableTxt(elem) {
    var id = $(elem).attr("id");
    alert(id);
}
```

Comment: you beat my answer in few seconds hmmm just kidding

Answer (score 10):

The html

```
 <button class="destroy" id="123">
```

The jQuery

```
  $('button.destroy').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.id);
```

Comment: I like your response, it is the cleanest. The one thing I don't understand is the `e.preventDefault();` line you added. Would you mind explaining to me why that is there?

Comment: Well if the button is in a form this will prevent the form from posting, that way it stays on the same page. It's not required in your question and can be ignored

Answer (score 5):

You can pass just the ID from the HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="name" id="name" onchange="enableTxt($(this).attr('id'))" />

function enableTxt(id)
{
    alert(id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

pass this to the function

```
enableTxt(this)

function enableTxt(item) {
    var id = $(item).attr("id");
    alert(id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
alert($("input:radio").attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This video might be helpful:- https://youtu.be/gO286Isc5FM

I was trying with `$(this).attr(id)`

But was returning an `undefined error`

But using this method(in the video) worked

My use case:
`<h1 id = "Autogenerated" Onclick="print(this)">AutoGeneratedlistItems<h1>"`

`function print(listItem){console.log(listItem.id) }`
which outputs the id of the `Clicked` element

Answer (score 0):

Another option is with JQ

```
$("#name").on('onchange',enableText);
```

With this your object will be the current *this*

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery onclick method be like :

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').click((e)=> {
  id = e.target.id;
  console.log('id = ',id);
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="name" id="name" />
<label for="name">Click Me</label>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```